# XPath: if child exists - get value, if not - write empty line

Tags: xpath

I have three node types: without categories, with a single category and multiple categories:

```
<technology>
  <categories>
    <category></category>
  </categories>
  <name></name>
</technologie>    

<technology>
  <name></name>
</technologie>    

<technology>
  <categories>
    <category></category>
    <category></category>
    <category></category>
  </categories>
  <name></name>
</technologie>
```

I want to write data from `technology` node like:

- if there is a single category - write it,
- if there is no category - write an empty line
- if there are multiple categories - write the first one.

I tried things like `//technology/*[descendant::category]`, or `//technology/categories/category[1]` - but **i fail on getting the empty line**, if `category` not exists, all existing categories are written one by one.

How do i get data written on the descripted way?

Comment: In XPath 1.0 the node-set data type is a proper set of nodes. It cannot be a non-node in a set of nodes.

Comment: XPath cannot "write" things, it can only select things. Writing things is done by the host language, based on what XPath selects. You need to tell us what the host language is. (In a comment on an answer, you suggest Excel/VBA).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the direction you want to take, but FWIW, you can handle it with lxml. If your code is:

```
snip = """
<technology>
  <categories>
    <category>Cat-A</category>
  </categories>
  <name>Nam-1</name>
</technology>    

<technology>
  <name>Nam-2</name>
</technology>    

<technology>
  <categories>
    <category>Cat-B</category>
    <category>Cat-C</category>
    <category>Cat-D</category>
  </categories>
  <name></name>
</technology>
  """
```

You can use:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(snip, parser=lxml.etree.HTMLParser())

results  =  tree.xpath("*//technology")
for result in results:
    for j in result.getchildren():
        if j.tag == 'categories':
            for m in j.itertext():
                if m.strip() != '':
                    print(m)
                    break
            break
        else:
            print('none')
            break
```

Output:

```
Cat-A
none
Cat-B
```

Comment: Thank you, but i'll not be able to get Python into Excel

Comment: @Evgeniy - Sorry, didn't realize it involved Excel... But I understand there are ways to run python code from VBA. See this for example: https://xlwings.readthedocs.io/en/v0.9.2/vba.html